# Image wont center in screen

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to center an image in the screen, that is for the splash screen. I am very new in XCODE that's why I'm asking this question. I am using Auto Layout and creating constraints using these: Horizontally in Container and Vertically in Container.

But the output is that the image is always in the top right. Please see this video: http://screencast.com/t/mWUnuGEutr

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: removed it but same problem stil

Comment: have you added different size images like, 1x,2x and 3x?

Comment: Remove Width and height constraints then try. No need for those constraints. (only Center X, Center Y ) is enough. It will take your Image's default size.

Comment: nothing changed. removed the width and height constraints and run the program.

Comment: What is the superview? What constraints does it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with auto layout and size classes is not as easy or intuitive as you might first think. To better understand the logic behind constraint-based layouts read Apple's [Understanding Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1) guide.

Make sure your view is generic (square) by selecting the 'Any' size class at the bottom: (read [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH6-SW1) for info on size classes)

[image: Size class]

Place the element in the center of the view (look for the blue guidelines):

[image: Centered label]

Click the icon in the bottom right and '*Reset to Suggested Constraints*' (or <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>)

[image: Reset to suggested constraints]

Now the element should be centered in your view at runtime:

[image: Simulator]

Comment: No matter where I place the image in the view, its position in runtime doesnt change.

Comment: Did you '*Reset to Suggested Constraints*' as well?

Comment: switched to wANY hANY and I just see white space

Comment: I removed other constraints except for centerX and centerY. The image is now showing correctly in the center but it is bigger that the left and right sides are cropped.

Comment: Make sure to set the correct view mode (i.e. '*aspect fit*') of your Image View in the attributes inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Just use constraints i.e Horizontally In Container,Vertically In Container,Height and Width and place image in center of View otherwise constraints will break.